# ExactTarget FirstName is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

How would I go about creating a greeting that's based on fields data. If `FirstName` isn't filled in and based on not it being filled in.

I tried this script below and still getting error messages on simple send.

```
%%[IF not empty(First Name) THEN]%% 
Hello, %%First Name%%. 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when a personalization string has a space in AMPscript, you need to house it in brackets ([]). (http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/)

> **Attribute and Data Extension (Custom Object) Values**
>
> Subscriber attribute, additional email attributes, and data extension
>   column values are referenced in functions and scripts as unquoted
>   strings. If the attribute, data extension column, table, or
>   relationship name includes a space or special character, it must be
>   enclosed in square brackets. For example:
>
> EmailAdr
>
> [Data Extension Attribute Name]
>
> [Total-Expense]
>
> You can define additional email attributes within the email and use
>   them in substitutions or as parameters in AMPscript function calls.
>   The Salesforce Marketing Cloud must enable the use of additional email
>   attributes for you account. Contact your Salesforce Marketing Cloud
>   relationship manager with any questions about this functionality.

I also prefer using AMPscript variables instead of the personalization string (which I used in below sample), but that is no means necessary for your need.

Try this:

```
%%[
VAR @Fname
SET @Fname = [First Name]

IF not empty(@Fname) THEN]%% 
Hello, %%=v(@Fname)=%%. 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Answer (score 2):

My preference is to use the [AttributeValue()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#AttributeValue) function in an init section and then utilize an [inline-if](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/#IIf) function:

```
%%[ 
/* Init Section */
VAR @Fname
SET @Fname = AttributeValue("First Name")
]%%

<!-- other HTML code here -->  

Hello%%=iif(empty(@Fname),"",concat(", ", @Fname))=%%.
```